# POST request with cpp-httplib

Tags: c++, http

I have found this header only library called [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib), which seems to work fine for my purposes. I need to control a camera through HTTP requests. For example, I can read the current position of the camera using:

```
httplib::Client cli("192.170.0.201", 8080);
auto res = cli.Get("/ptz.stats/present_pos");
```

which corresponds to the following Curl command;

> curl -X GET "http://192.170.0.201:8080/ptz.stats/present_pos"

Now, I want to move the camera using a POST request. With curl, I can use following command to move the camera to left:

> curl -X POST "http://192.170.0.201:8080/ptz.cmd/?pan_left=50"

I want to make the exact same POST request from `httplib` using

```
httplib::Client cli("192.170.0.201", 8080);
httplib::Params params{
  { "pan_left", "50" }
};
auto p = cli.Post("/ptz.cmd", params);
```

and this does nothing. I can see the camera and that curl command moves it. So, am I translating the POST request to `httplib` format in a wrong way? How would you call that curl request in `httplib`?

PS: `httplib` might not be a popular library but it has neat documentation and I think anyone working with web requests and C++ can help.

Comment: Shouldn't this be { "?pan_left", "50" }?

Comment: I thought "?" would be added automatically but anyways, tried adding it as well. It does not work that way either. I know it is impossible for others to test since I have a physical camera. Still, it is more about HTTP parameters than the camera itself.

Answer (score 4):

Related question:
[How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

POST parameters are not sent in the URI. From the [cpp-httplib github](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib), you can sent url-encoded parameters using:

```
cli.Post("/ptz.cmd", "pan_left=50", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```